# WordPress: Looping multiple custom fields from a post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-fields

I've recently come to a project where using custom fields would be pretty handy. It's for a restaurant and if I can get this right, I could use this bit of code for a few different sections of the site.

I'm using the Magic Fields 2 plugin and right now it's awesome, except for when it comes to displaying the fields I've created. Here's where I'm getting pretty lost.

For example, I have a post called "Specials" and that has a grouping called "Menu Item" and that group has two fields called "Name" and "Description". Basically name serves as the menu item name, and description will be a small blurb about the food item.

Here's the code in my theme for this section right now:

```
<div id="specials">
<?php 
$query2 = get_post(28);
$title = $query2->post_title;
$itemname= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu_item_name', true);
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu_item_description', true);

?>
    <div id="specialstitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
    <div class="stripebackbrown">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="specialslist">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

echo '<span>'.$itemname.'</span>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
?>
    </div>


</div><!-- end specials-->
```

Now there is a very good chance what I'm doing in the above code is completely wrong, if it is, please let me know.
What I'm experiencing with the above code however is it's pulling the very first group for that post.

So instead of something like:

**Tomato Soup**
*description text here*

**Turkey Sandwich**
*description text here*

**Greek Salad**
*description text here*

I'm getting:

**Tomato Soup**
*description text here*

**Tomato Soup**
*description text here*

**Tomato Soup**
*description text here*

So while the above code is technically working, it's not working properly at the same time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I'm having some better success with this:

```
<div id="specials">

<?php 
$query2 = get_post(28);
$title = $query2->post_title;
?>
    <div id="specialstitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
    <div class="stripebackbrown">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="specialslist">

<?php $itemname = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'menu_item_name', false); ?>
<?php $description = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'menu_item_description', false); ?>

<?php foreach ($itemname as $itemname){

echo '<span>' .$itemname. '</span>';

echo '<p>' .$description. '</p>';

} ?>
    </div>


</div><!-- end specials-->
```

However, I'm not sure how to add $description to that foreach loop. So right now it's listing out the menu names but adding "Array" where the description should be. Getting closer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this like that:

```
<div id="specials">
<?php 
$query2 = get_post(28);
$title = $query2->post_title;

?>
    <div id="specialstitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
    <div class="stripebackbrown">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="specialslist">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$itemname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_name', true);
$description = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_description', true);

echo '<span>'.$itemname.'</span>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
?>
    </div>
```

Comment: That did stop the repeating issue, but, with this answer now it only lists the first grouped Name and Description, and doesn't list the ones that follow that are also attached to that post.

Comment: So you want to tell me that `$itemname` is array?

Comment: I'm not sure really. Basically I have grouped custom fields for this post, and then that group of custom fields can be repeated for adding different items. So there would be multiple instances of $itemname and $description. I don't know if that falls under an array. It very well might. Hopefully I'm explaining this right but I wanted to loop the $itemname and $description part for each instance of those that appear on a particular post. The specials one for example has like 5 menu items in total. each with a name and description.

Comment: Try this `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_name', true));` and after that this: `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_name'));`. Let me know about results.

Comment: Going off of yours, upon doing var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_name', true)); I got string 'Tomato Soup' (length=11)
description of item
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
With var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'menu_item_name')); I got array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Tomato Soup' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Turkey Sandwich' (length=15)
  2 => string 'Greek Salad' (length=11)
description of item

array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
<?php 
$query2 = get_post(28);
$title = $query2->post_title;
?>
    <div id="specialstitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
    <div class="stripebackbrown">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="specialslist">

<?php $itemname = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'menu_item_name', false); ?>
<?php $description = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'menu_item_description', false); ?>

<?php foreach (array_combine($itemname, $description) as $itemname => $description){

echo '<span>' .$itemname. '</span>';

echo '<p>' .$description. '</p>';

} ?>
    </div>


</div><!-- end specials-->
```

This combines the two arrays created by $itemname and $description and loops them as many times as there are groups to loop.

@speccode, thanks so much for trying to help me, your reordering of my two lines got me heading in the right direction.

Comment: This was my next suggestion but I went to slepp. Good that you figured it out by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I've encountered a problem though, maybe you could help me. I tried the above code on a custom page template I made. Now it's pulling up the post via the ID, like the Stitle of the post is displaying properly. However, it's not pulling up the custom fields attached to that post. Maybe because it's being used on a custom template page?

Comment: You have to double check method of getting post id. `var_dump($post->ID)` or `var_dump(get_the_ID())`. Also check if there is really meta data for that specific post.

Comment: I think...it's pulling the id from the page instead. I kept getting an ID of 4 listed, and I had it give me the title of what id number that is and it's the Menu page itself.

Comment: So how it's a custom post page if you're getting page id?

Comment: Well it's a post I'm referencing on a custom template page. If that makes more sense. My plan for this page by the way was to pull up multiple posts in different places on the page, and build a master menu out of that. So like this specials section would come from one post, breakfast would come from another. That sort of set up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same problem so I attempted to improved @speccode answers' a tiny bit and it seems to work:

```
<?php $itemnames = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'itemnames', false); ?>
<?php $descriptions = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'descriptions', false); ?>

<?php foreach (array_combine($itemnames, $descriptions) as $itemname => $description)
   {
     echo '<img src="'.$itemname.'"/>';
     echo '<p>' .$description. '</p>';
  } 
?>
```

I also attempted abit of structuring in there *(see below)* but I can't guarantee the validity of the markup... *anyone*?

```
<?php $itemnames = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'itemnames', false); ?>
<?php $descriptions = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'descriptions', false); ?>

<?php foreach (array_combine($itemnames, $descriptions) as $itemname => $description)
   {
     echo '<div class="nameAndDescription"><img src="'.$itemname.'"/>';
     echo '<p>' .$description. '</p></div>';
  } 
?>
```