# Which method is best for retrieving information from custom fields in a Wordpress post to be displayed on another page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a PHP beginner working with Wordpress, and I'm trying to retrieve data from custom fields (using Custom Field Suite) from a post to be displayed on a different page.

I have tried a few different ways, and found two methods that work. But as I'm a beginner, I wonder if these methods are 'proper'?

This is one solution I found, but it's not exactly elegant:

```
// Method 1
$current = CFS()->get( 'get_current' ); //retrieves the post ID from a custom field on the page
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($current);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['current_title'];
$my_custom_field2 = $custom_fields['current_artist'];

foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key) {
}
foreach ( $my_custom_field2 as $key2) {
}

echo '<h2>'.$key.'</h2>';
echo '<h1>'.$key2.'</h1>';
```

I tried to re-write it like this, but nothing is displayed - not sure what's wrong with this loop:

```
// Method 2
$current = CFS()->get( 'get_current' ); 
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($current);

foreach ( $custom_fields as $key) {

echo '<h2>'.$key['current_title'].'</h2>';
echo '<h1>'.$key['current_artist'].'</h1>';
}
```

As method 2 wasn't working, I tried something else and found that this also works (I added the loop here based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918170/5483154):

```
 // Method 3
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 $current = CFS()->get( 'get_current' );
 $currentitle = get_post_meta($current, 'current_title', true);
 $artistname = get_post_meta($current, 'current_artist', true);

 echo '<h2>'.$currentitle.'</h2>';
 echo '<h1>'.$artistname.'</h1>';

 endwhile;
 wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

Method 3 seems best to me. Is this a good way of approaching this problem? And if anyone would be kind enough to explain what's wrong with method 2, I would also appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this? Don't forget to vote up the answer if it helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Custom Field Suite documentation here: http://customfieldsuite.com/api/get.html

It looks like you should be using the 'get' method:

```
CFS()->get( $field_name, $post_id, $options );
```

Eg.

```
$current = CFS()->get( 'get_current' );     

echo '<h2>' . CFS()->get( 'current_title', $current ) . '</h2>';
echo '<h1>' . CFS()->get( 'current_artist', $current ) . '</h1>';
```

Ps. Don't forget to watch the order of your heading tags (`<h1>` should come before `<h2>`)

Answer (score -1):

In the case of your "method 2": what if you try rewriting it something like this?

```
// Method 2
$current = CFS()->get('get_current');
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($current);

foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
    foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the recommended way to get custom fields using Custom Field Suite and, presumably, the OP would like to display the custom fields in the order that they specify rather than outputting in the order in which they are stored with a foreach... Always best to follow the documentation... ;-)

Comment: You're right , although I was replying to this statement by the poster:

"And if anyone would be kind enough to explain what's wrong with method 2, I would also appreciate it. Thanks". It seemed as if the poster misunderstood the structure of the returned data from `get_post_custom()` which I tried to show in code.